# Audio jack acts like an antenna?

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone

I am using a simple pre-amplifier circuit for an electret microphone.

Here's the schematic and the AC transfer function:

[image: Pre amplifier]

[image]

The output is connected to a 3.5mm audio jack through a couple of half a meter wires. I tested the circuit on a breadboard and was able to ensure that the circuit works. I used an oscilloscope to view the output as I was speaking to the microphone.

Here comes the problem:

When I tried to connect the audio jack to my phone and record a voice I noticed a lot of noise picked up on my recorded voice. To come up with an explanation for this I believe the audio jack itself would act like an antenna and pick up some high frequency signals lying all around.

To verify this I connected the probe to the output while kept everything quiet. I observed some 20mV peak-to-peak noise signals with frequencies ranging between 40-80kHz.

So it seems I'm right. If so, what should I do to remove the unwanted noise? Should I use a low pass filter right before the audio jack is connected to the phone?

EDIT

Here's my setup. I have not used any decoupling capacitors on power supply yet. I will update the question after using a decoupling cap to see where it goes. Also note that I used a UA741 not Op07.

[image]

Comment: Did you use screened cable for the microphone?

Comment: Put the amplifier at the microphone, either with a battery or power fed through chokes to prevent pickup on the power lines.  Professional setups would go a step further and use differential signalling.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, the wires are soldered on the audio jack.

Comment: "*Yes, the wires are soldered on the audio jack.*" Proper screened microphone cable? A photo of your setup might be useful.

Comment: How did you power that amplifier? With a 5V USB switch mode power supply?

Comment: 40 to 80 kHz doesn't sound like an antenna at all (antennas for 40 kHz are basically very large, or many windings of wires, usually on a ferrite core), but like you're coupling in noise from elsewhere. An easy way to check where the noise comes from would be trying to add RC lowpass filters on the inputs, power supply, ground connections. You'd usually add a lowpass to the input, anyway, or use a capacitor in parallel with your feedback resistor to reduce the gain at high frequencies.

Comment: I see no power supply decoupling here : that can't help.

Comment: @Justme not exactly from a USB, but yes through a SMPS adaptor. Sp yeah I know it might be due to the switching noise. Let me add a decoupling cap and see what it does

Comment: Since the SMPS powers the board via linear regulators, it may not be ripple and noise of the 5V itself, but common mode noise of the SMPS.

Comment: Why are you even using a preamp? The microphone input in the smartphone is designed for the signal from a microphone. You've increased the noise level 40 dB while the spoken audio is probably being compressed by the phones automatic level control circuit.